# Why does Google-search behave differently using FireFox and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, google-search

I wanted to edit my web page (http://www.cominter.com/annonce/QLXannonces.html.) on  my smartphone (Samsung galaxy note 2) and my desktop (windows 7)  using two different browsers: chrome and Firefox. With chrome, I get the right page but with FireFox I got other pages as you can see from the screen shots below.

Does this mean that google page rendering may change according to the browser used? Any advice or explanation is welcome.

[image: Google search result using FireFox]
[image: Google search result using Chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google takes your search history and browser history into account, this is why you would get different results.

To get the most neutral search results try opening a incognito window in chrome or with firefox open a "Private Window". This can be done on desktop or mobile.

Comment: 1) I am using google in both firefox and chrome. In the search box I type the url of the web page. google chrome give the requested page but not google firefox.

Comment: 2) I opened a "Private Window" in firefox; then go to google and type the url; the result includes the previous results  + others including my question here because it contains the url (I guess), but still it does not give the requested url. In conclusion, when using firefox, google is looking in the pages to find the url, like it was a keyword, which is quite annoying.